# R stacked bar plot without increment the values in the bars

Tags: r, stacked-chart

I am starting with R, and trying to draw a stacked bar plot, my data is this:

```
   Groups AxisX AxisY
1       B     1 35476
2       B     2 31394
3       B     3 39305
4       B     4 33845
5       B     5 30295
6       B     6 25590
7       B     7 32197
8       B     8 27901
9       B     9 35936
10      B    10 31341
11      A     1 46468
12      A     2 42557
13      A     3 55158
14      A     4 49182
15      A     5 44825
16      A     6 39813
17      A     7 44900
18      A     8 40964
19      A     9 47823
20      A    10 44373
```

It was created with this command:

```
dfx <- data.frame(Groups=rep(c("B", "A"), each=10),
                AxisX=rep(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"),2),
                AxisY=c(35476,31394,39305,33845,30295,25590,32197,27901,35936,31341,46468,42557,55158,49182,44825,39813,44900,40964,47823,44373))
```

I want to graph this data using the stacked bar plot, but this is incrementing the value by bar, for example for:

```
B     1 35476
A     1 46468
```

I would like to have:

```
46468 |
35476 |
0     |
```

and not in this way:

```
81944 |
35476 |
0     |
```

I'm using this code to graph:

```
p <- ggplot(data=dfx, aes(x=AxisX, y=AxisY, fill=Groups)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

If I add the `position=position_dodge()` is ok, but I'd like to have the graphic overlapped.

What changes I need to do? or I need to use other method to have the graphic will be as I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your data to plot the picture you want. If you need only differences between groups, then compute them first.

```
require("dplyr")

ggplot(data=dfx %>% group_by(AxisX) %>% arrange(AxisY) %>% 
         mutate(AxisY_2 = c(AxisY[1], diff(AxisY))),
       aes(x=AxisX, y=AxisY_2, fill=Groups)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you answer!